# Why does Oracle Fusion EBS use both ENABLED_FLAG and START_DATE_ACTIVE/END_DATE_ACTIVE in its database tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs, oracle-fusion-apps

A number of the Oracle EBS tables include the columns `ENABLED_FLAG`, `START_DATE_ACTIVE`, and `END_DATE_ACTIVE` which are used to determine whether the row is available in the application or not.

For example to get a list of the current lookup codes from the `FND_LOOKUP` table I would run the following SQL query

```
select lookup_code 
from fnd_lookups fl
where and fl.enabled_flag = 'Y' and sysdate between nvl(fl.start_date_active,sysdate) and nvl(fl.end_date_active,sysdate)
```

My question is why is there an `ENABLED_FLAG` given that the `START_DATE_ACTIVE` and `END_DATE_ACTIVE` appear to be sufficient to determine whether the row should be available in the application? Is there another purpose for `ENABLED_FLAG` which I'm not seeing?

Comment: That's not a programming question - I'll vote to close.  But, remember two things.  First - a lot of that Application Object Library code was legacy stuff built 30 years ago.  It's very possible they started with just "enabled_flag" and later decided they needed dates but couldn't get rid of "enabled_flag".  Second, unchecking the "enabled_flag" makes a record unusable, even for backdated transactions, so there is a functional difference.

Comment: Note that Oracle Fusion and Oracle EBS are different products.  Although Fusion may have the same pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matthew mentions - this is primarily historical.  A table such as FND_LOOKUPS is referenced thousands of times in the code.  As such, there's no easy way to change the existing semantics - you can only add on new semantics.

On the plus side, you only need to do this when allowing the values to be chosen, and not when joining...